# Angular Bootstrap Popover takes 2 clicks to open after closing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have multiple popovers that I have on grid cells that I use the append-to-body="true" attribute on them.  When I scroll down the grid, I want to programatically hide the popups.

Currently I'm using this code to hide them

```
     function closeAllPopOvers() {
        var popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popover');
        if(popups) {
            for(var i=0; i<popups.length; i++) {
                var popup = popups[i];
                var popupElement = angular.element(popup);
                popupElement.scope().$parent.isOpen = false;
                popupElement.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem this presents is that if I go back to one of the popovers that was closed by this code it takes 2 clicks to open.  What is the proper way to close all popovers that are append-to-body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're messing up the popover trigger setup, try setting `popover-trigger` to `none`

```
popover-trigger="'none'"
```

and then provide an expression to `popover-is-open`

```
popover-is-open="$expression_result"
```

when that expression will evaluate to `false` your popover will close (and vice-versa)

p.s.

I've noticed you're getting your popovers using this line

```
var popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popover');
```

Don't, It would be easier to hold an array of expressions inside your controller, whose items are bound to each `popover-is-open`, then on certain events, you can easily traverse that array and manipulate your popovers.

Comment: Thanks - I had the trigger set to click. I changed the trigger to none, and used an array to hold all the values of popover-is-open.  popover-is-open is set to a function that finds the value in the array for the specific popover.